# Wordpress: Add html code to widget area without using a text widget

Tags: php, wordpress

Normally, you can create a text widget if you want to add html code to the sidebar area of Wordpress. But this won't work in my case, let me explain it to you:

I want to place an image (with an link) to the sidebar, which doesn't end up in a widget box with white background. Instead the image should be placed directly in the widget area.

Currently, my wordpress theme applies a white background to all widgets with the css class `.widget` by default. As far as I know, every widget is assigned with this class.

Is there a way to inject the html code using a hook in the functions.php of my theme folder? Or maybe using the sidebar.php file?

Comment: Hi otaku, my internet is not working in pc so will give you the exact details and codes for creating a new widget for your requirement. Please wait for a while till it gets back...

Comment: Try PHP code widget, it might be work for you

Comment: I don't think so. Because this is also a widget, this will have the .widget class in it -> widget box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

```
if ( !class_exists( 'MyCustomWidgetClass' ) ) {
        // Create Custom Draggable Widget  
    class MyCustomWidgetClass extends WP_Widget {
        // Register widget with WordPress.
        public function __construct() {

            parent::__construct(
                'my_custom_widget', 
                'My Custom Widget Title', 
                array( 'description' => __( 'Custom Widget Decription', 'cmk' ), ) 
            );
        }
        //Front-end display of widget.
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            $content = 'Bla Bla'; // Add HTML code, or call the function that contains your HTML code
            extract( $args );
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $before_widget;
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
            echo $content;
            echo $after_widget;
        }

        //Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
            return $instance;
        }

        // Back-end widget form.
        public function form( $instance ) {
            if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            } else {
                $title = __( 'My Custom Widget Title', 'cmk' );
            } ?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            </p><?php 
        }

    } 
    add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("MyCustomWidgetClass");') );
}
```

Comment: Good starting point. The problem is, that this will also have the CSS class *.widget*, so that the updated html code will be inside a white box. Is there a way to remove the widget class from the code of the newly created widget?

Comment: why don't you simply apply your css to something like ```.widget:not('.customwidgetclass')``` to avoid the property from applying to the widget you don't want to have a white box, you can also simply remove that class using jquery ```$('#my_widget_ID').removeClass('widget');```

Comment: Thanks, this was the first time I heard of the :not-selector in CSS3. Now I got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inline css to change the background color of your image if you want to add image using text widget.

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">
<img src="Your Image Path" style="background-color: beige;">
</a>
```